# How to make a list with multiple column in each row in Sencha touch?

Tags: html, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I want a list with multiple columns in each row. The row also can consist the image. I am able to get the values from store. But unable to display them in a proper way.  i need the view like below:

[image]

Please help. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is how I do it. Create a view for the list as seen below. 
Not sure how you are creating your views so add extra code if your still having trouble.

```
Ext.define('AppName.view.CustomList', {
  extend: 'Ext.List',
  xtype: 'customlist',
  config: {
    store: 'StoreName',
    itemTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                '<div style="float:left; width: 50%">{Column1Name}</div>',
                '<div style="float:left; width: 50%">{Column2Name}</div>',
                '<div style="clear:both"></div>'
        )
  }
});
```

EDIT: the following is an update that would be the layout you could use. It should be close, you may need to clear:both another place and I am sure this could be cleaner but I am just giving you something to work with.

```
 itemTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
            '<div>',
              '<div style="float:left; width: 30%">{firstName}</div>',
              '<div style="float:left; width: 40%">{feedbackHeading}</div>',
              '<div style="float:left; width: 30%">{date}</div>',
            '</div>',
            '<div>',
              '<div style="float:left; width: 30%">{lastName}</div>',
              '<div style="float:left; width: 40%">{feedbackSummary}</div>',
              '<div style="float:left; width: 30%">{location}</div>',
            '</div>',
            '<div style="clear:both"></div>'
    )
```

Comment: i tried with the below code:        itemTpl:  Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                                           '<div style="font-size: 1">{firstName}</div><div style="font-size: 1">{lastName}<br/></div><div style="font-size: 1">{heading}</div>'
                   )                                                                                    But the field are coming one after another vertically

Comment: Of course they will. Divs take up the width of the parent. Not to mention, <br/> is a line break which will also cause more space.
You need to use something similiar to what I have above to make it work correctly. Try something small first like the following
    '<div style="float:left; width:50%">{firstName}</div><div style="float:left; width:50%">{lastName}</div><div style="clear:both"></div>'

The style tags I have are essential if you use divs.

Try looking up some basic html. Sencha in the end is nothing but html, css, and javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do with div structure means div within div according to your data.